# Iterating an Arraylist of Arraylists using forEach and lambda expression

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

I have an **ArrayList**

```java
List<List<Integer>> nestedlists = new ArrayList<>();
```

How to iterate this list using forEach and lambda Expression.

for example an Arraylist can be iterated as:-

```java
List<Integer> singlelist = new ArrayList<>();
singlelist.forEach((ele)->System.out.println(ele));
```

How to do the same for ArrayList containing Arraylists.

Comment: Just the same way, `list.forEach(x -> x.forEach(y -> System.out.println(y)));` or perhaps with better names: `list.forEach(sub -> sub.forEach(i -> System.out.println(i)));`

Comment: @Holger or ... *perhaps with better names: `nestedLists.forEach(sub -> sub.forEach(i -> System.out.println(i)));`* ?

Comment: @Naman well, I didn’t want to change what’s perhaps given by the task. However, if we change the name, it would be even better to have a name which reflects the purpose of the list, rather than the fact that it is a nested list, which we can already derive from its type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Stream`s with `flatMap`:

```
list.stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Which one will have better performance using streams or the otherway

Comment: @SomilGarg Are you really concerned about the performance of a `System.out.print`? The difference between the two would anyway be trivial, given the task executed. Even if you want, you can rather benchmark them and test them.